# C# equivalent to wildcard imports in Java

Tags: c#, namespaces

Is there a way in C# to import everything inside a namespace like there is in Java with the wildcard character?

```
import java.awt.*;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's what the normal using directive does. For instance:

```
using System;
```

means you can use Console, Guid, Int32 etc without qualification. The closest equivalent to the *single* import in Java is:

```
using Console = System.Console;
```

(etc)

but that's not used very often.

Comment: Thats something that I did not know could be done in C#, I kind-of like it because you only use Console but the syntax is really uncomfortable.

Comment: It's more useful for getting round naming clashes, e.g. having "Button" imported from two different namespaces.

Comment: Or when your testers insist on having really long namespaces. :)

Comment: Aliases are also useful for shortening or clarifying long names, which sometimes happens with generics.