# C# how to import namespaces at once

Tags: c#, .net

I'd want to use something like this

```
using mynamespace.*
```

which will import mynamespace and all namespaces below but this doesn't seem to work is it possible 
?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Equivalent to import java.awt.*;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583944/c-equivalent-to-import-java-awt)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  He's asking for importing a heirarchy, which you can't do in C# OR Java.

Comment: @JonathonFaust yes it's a perfect duplicate, the purpose is always to write `a.*` to import `a.A`, `a.b.B1`, `a.b.B2`, `a.b.c.C` etc., so there's always a hierarchy of namespaces implied.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such directive in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do that im afraid