# Import all subpackages at once in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to import all subpackages at once in Java?

As I learned it seems possible in C#:

[C# how to import namespaces at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806986/c-how-to-import-namespaces-at-once)

Comment: Well done sir, rep farming at its best.

Comment: @Oded: Ug, I just noticed that the linked question has my _exact_ answer in a comment linking to a duplicate question.  I'll just delete my answer below, it's better for the universe.

Comment: Similar questions with useful answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319016/1460043, https://stackoverflow.com/q/31577589/1460043

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

will import only the classes in the `javax.swing` package.  It will not import subpackages such as `javax.swing.event`.  You would need a separate import for each subpackage:

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
```

Comment: But this news is not so bad. IDEs help you to import all needed packages. For example in Eclipse you can press Ctrl+Shift-O and all your imports are written automatically.