# For Java, can I import all packages at once?

Tags: java

For example, the third party library uses very complex directory structure for the package.
Can I import them at once. the star seems can only imports one directory level.

Comment: Why don't you use an IDE like Eclipse which can automatically import everything you need?

Comment: Minimize imports, ideally only to the specific classes you need.  As @WoLpH notes, any decent IDE will do this for you.  Overbroad imports are noisy and the source of confusing namespace shadowing issues.

Comment: Just to get over the minimum character limit: no.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you're asking whether or not you can do something like:

```
import com.example.*;
// expecting packages like com.example.foo.* and com.example.bar.* to be imported
```

Then the answer is **no**. The widest import you can make is a single package with a star.

The JLS (section 7.5) [defines](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/packages.doc.html#26658) the structure for import statements.

Additionally, it would be problematic for the compiler to import a bunch of packages at once. If two packages provide the same type, both are imported, and the type is used in the class, a compile-time error occurs. This is described in [JLS 6.5.5.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#32799):

> Otherwise, if a type of that name is
>   declared by more than one
>   type-import-on-demand declaration of
>   the compilation unit, then the name is
>   ambiguous as a type name; a
>   compile-time error occurs.

Comment: @Rob, However, many classes in sub-packages are purposely named such that they would not have conflicting class names. Would be great if they allowed double-asterisks in future Java versions, e.g. `a.b.c.**` for importing everything within `a.b.c`.

Answer (score 4):

As you pointed in java you can only use "one level" import used by "*"

The more effective way is to open Eclipse, open class where imports should be and press: CTRL + SHIFT + O:) - nowadays all IDE helps with organize imports

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest, as others have done, that you use the "organize imports" from your IDE (most major java IDE will do this).

Also, I advice against using "*" in your imports, and the reason for this is simple. At some time, you might want to upgrade one of the library that you import (or the jdk) and you might end up with name clashes due to some new classes in a package (this is especially true for the static imports). It might not be a big deal if that happens to a class inside your current project, but if you make that code into a library at some point, it might be more problematic as you will have to recompile that class after adjusting the conflicting imports.

(Yes, that happened to me not so long ago... It was a pain as I had to hunt down the library source code to rebuild.)

Save yourself some trouble down the road. :D

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, you can't import all packages at once. However, its not like the end of the world. If you use a good IDE like Intellij, it would add import statements with appropriate package name automatically to your code as soon as you write the code which is using a class/interface from that package.

There is another way if you want to import everything at once. This is not at all recommended but the trick is to go to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/allpackages-index.html to check the list of all packages, save that html page on your local system, open the html code. remove all tags from head tag and add this code:

```
<style>
    .block { display: none;}
</style>
```

After this, save the document and open it in a browser, you'll see the package names clearly without any description. Now, you can just copy-paste them and give them as input to a simple java program that converts them into proper import statements.

The final result is:

```
import com.sun.jarsigner.*;
import com.sun.java.accessibility.util.*;
import com.sun.jdi.*;
import com.sun.jdi.connect.*;
import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.*;
import com.sun.jdi.event.*;
import com.sun.jdi.request.*;
import com.sun.management.*;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.*;
import com.sun.nio.sctp.*;
import com.sun.security.auth.*;
import com.sun.security.auth.callback.*;
import com.sun.security.auth.login.*;
import com.sun.security.auth.module.*;
import com.sun.security.jgss.*;
import com.sun.source.doctree.*;
import com.sun.source.tree.*;
import com.sun.source.util.*;
import com.sun.tools.attach.*;
import com.sun.tools.attach.spi.*;
import com.sun.tools.javac.*;
import com.sun.tools.jconsole.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.desktop.*;
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.im.*;
import java.awt.im.spi.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.image.renderable.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.beans.beancontext.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.constant.*;
import java.lang.instrument.*;
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.lang.management.*;
import java.lang.module.*;
import java.lang.ref.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.http.*;
import java.net.spi.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.channels.spi.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.charset.spi.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.nio.file.spi.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.activation.*;
import java.rmi.dgc.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.security.interfaces.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.text.spi.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.chrono.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;
import java.time.zone.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.jar.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.prefs.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.spi.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import javax.accessibility.*;
import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.interfaces.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.event.*;
import javax.imageio.metadata.*;
import javax.imageio.plugins.bmp.*;
import javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg.*;
import javax.imageio.plugins.tiff.*;
import javax.imageio.spi.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.*;
import javax.lang.model.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.*;
import javax.lang.model.type.*;
import javax.lang.model.util.*;
import javax.management.*;
import javax.management.loading.*;
import javax.management.modelmbean.*;
import javax.management.monitor.*;
import javax.management.openmbean.*;
import javax.management.relation.*;
import javax.management.remote.*;
import javax.management.remote.rmi.*;
import javax.management.timer.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import javax.naming.event.*;
import javax.naming.ldap.*;
import javax.naming.ldap.spi.*;
import javax.naming.spi.*;
import javax.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;
import javax.print.event.*;
import javax.rmi.ssl.*;
import javax.script.*;
import javax.security.auth.*;
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
import javax.security.auth.kerberos.*;
import javax.security.auth.login.*;
import javax.security.auth.spi.*;
import javax.security.auth.x500.*;
import javax.security.cert.*;
import javax.security.sasl.*;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.sound.midi.spi.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.spi.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.sql.rowset.*;
import javax.sql.rowset.serial.*;
import javax.sql.rowset.spi.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.colorchooser.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.multi.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.*;
import javax.swing.text.rtf.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import javax.swing.undo.*;
import javax.tools.*;
import javax.transaction.xa.*;
import javax.xml.*;
import javax.xml.catalog.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dom.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.*;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.events.*;
import javax.xml.stream.util.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.validation.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import jdk.dynalink.*;
import jdk.dynalink.beans.*;
import jdk.dynalink.linker.*;
import jdk.dynalink.linker.support.*;
import jdk.dynalink.support.*;
import jdk.javadoc.doclet.*;
import jdk.jfr.*;
import jdk.jfr.consumer.*;
import jdk.jshell.*;
import jdk.jshell.execution.*;
import jdk.jshell.spi.*;
import jdk.jshell.tool.*;
import jdk.management.jfr.*;
import jdk.net.*;
import jdk.nio.*;
import jdk.security.jarsigner.*;
import netscape.javascript.*;
import org.ietf.jgss.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.*;
import org.w3c.dom.css.*;
import org.w3c.dom.events.*;
import org.w3c.dom.html.*;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.*;
import org.w3c.dom.ranges.*;
import org.w3c.dom.stylesheets.*;
import org.w3c.dom.traversal.*;
import org.w3c.dom.views.*;
import org.w3c.dom.xpath.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.ext.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;
```

You can just copy-paste this to your .java files

Here's the java code that converts the name of packages to import statements:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class import_everything {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = new String[233];
        int i = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (i < 223) {
            s[i] = sc.next();
            s[i] = "import " + s[i] + ".*;";
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < 223) {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the list of all the java packages obtained by changing html code of the official documentation provided at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/allpackages-index.html :

```
com.sun.jarsigner
com.sun.java.accessibility.util
com.sun.jdi
com.sun.jdi.connect
com.sun.jdi.connect.spi
com.sun.jdi.event
com.sun.jdi.request
com.sun.management
com.sun.net.httpserver
com.sun.net.httpserver.spi
com.sun.nio.sctp
com.sun.security.auth
com.sun.security.auth.callback
com.sun.security.auth.login
com.sun.security.auth.module
com.sun.security.jgss
com.sun.source.doctree
com.sun.source.tree
com.sun.source.util
com.sun.tools.attach
com.sun.tools.attach.spi
com.sun.tools.javac
com.sun.tools.jconsole
java.applet
java.awt
java.awt.color
java.awt.datatransfer
java.awt.desktop
java.awt.dnd
java.awt.event
java.awt.font
java.awt.geom
java.awt.im
java.awt.im.spi
java.awt.image
java.awt.image.renderable
java.awt.print
java.beans
java.beans.beancontext
java.io
java.lang
java.lang.annotation
java.lang.constant
java.lang.instrument
java.lang.invoke
java.lang.management
java.lang.module
java.lang.ref
java.lang.reflect
java.math
java.net
java.net.http
java.net.spi
java.nio
java.nio.channels
java.nio.channels.spi
java.nio.charset
java.nio.charset.spi
java.nio.file
java.nio.file.attribute
java.nio.file.spi
java.rmi
java.rmi.activation
java.rmi.dgc
java.rmi.registry
java.rmi.server
java.security
java.security.acl
java.security.cert
java.security.interfaces
java.security.spec
java.sql
java.text
java.text.spi
java.time
java.time.chrono
java.time.format
java.time.temporal
java.time.zone
java.util
java.util.concurrent
java.util.concurrent.atomic
java.util.concurrent.locks
java.util.function
java.util.jar
java.util.logging
java.util.prefs
java.util.regex
java.util.spi
java.util.stream
java.util.zip
javax.accessibility
javax.annotation.processing
javax.crypto
javax.crypto.interfaces
javax.crypto.spec
javax.imageio
javax.imageio.event
javax.imageio.metadata
javax.imageio.plugins.bmp
javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg
javax.imageio.plugins.tiff
javax.imageio.spi
javax.imageio.stream
javax.lang.model
javax.lang.model.element
javax.lang.model.type
javax.lang.model.util
javax.management
javax.management.loading
javax.management.modelmbean
javax.management.monitor
javax.management.openmbean
javax.management.relation
javax.management.remote
javax.management.remote.rmi
javax.management.timer
javax.naming
javax.naming.directory
javax.naming.event
javax.naming.ldap
javax.naming.ldap.spi
javax.naming.spi
javax.net
javax.net.ssl
javax.print
javax.print.attribute
javax.print.attribute.standard
javax.print.event
javax.rmi.ssl
javax.script
javax.security.auth
javax.security.auth.callback
javax.security.auth.kerberos
javax.security.auth.login
javax.security.auth.spi
javax.security.auth.x500
javax.security.cert
javax.security.sasl
javax.smartcardio
javax.sound.midi
javax.sound.midi.spi
javax.sound.sampled
javax.sound.sampled.spi
javax.sql
javax.sql.rowset
javax.sql.rowset.serial
javax.sql.rowset.spi
javax.swing
javax.swing.border
javax.swing.colorchooser
javax.swing.event
javax.swing.filechooser
javax.swing.plaf
javax.swing.plaf.basic
javax.swing.plaf.metal
javax.swing.plaf.multi
javax.swing.plaf.nimbus
javax.swing.plaf.synth
javax.swing.table
javax.swing.text
javax.swing.text.html
javax.swing.text.html.parser
javax.swing.text.rtf
javax.swing.tree
javax.swing.undo
javax.tools
javax.transaction.xa
javax.xml
javax.xml.catalog
javax.xml.crypto
javax.xml.crypto.dom
javax.xml.crypto.dsig
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec
javax.xml.datatype
javax.xml.namespace
javax.xml.parsers
javax.xml.stream
javax.xml.stream.events
javax.xml.stream.util
javax.xml.transform
javax.xml.transform.dom
javax.xml.transform.sax
javax.xml.transform.stax
javax.xml.transform.stream
javax.xml.validation
javax.xml.xpath
jdk.dynalink
jdk.dynalink.beans
jdk.dynalink.linker
jdk.dynalink.linker.support
jdk.dynalink.support
jdk.javadoc.doclet
jdk.jfr
jdk.jfr.consumer
jdk.jshell
jdk.jshell.execution
jdk.jshell.spi
jdk.jshell.tool
jdk.management.jfr
jdk.nashorn.api.scripting
jdk.nashorn.api.tree
jdk.net
jdk.nio
jdk.security.jarsigner
netscape.javascript
org.ietf.jgss
org.w3c.dom
org.w3c.dom.bootstrap
org.w3c.dom.css
org.w3c.dom.events
org.w3c.dom.html
org.w3c.dom.ls
org.w3c.dom.ranges
org.w3c.dom.stylesheets
org.w3c.dom.traversal
org.w3c.dom.views
org.w3c.dom.xpath
org.xml.sax
org.xml.sax.ext
org.xml.sax.helpers
```

Answer (score 0):

As In the case of JSPs,can I use a .inc file to import all the required classes from 3rd party libraries in a java class

Answer (score 0):

You can import only one directory level.

In IntelliJ Ctrl + Alt + O shortcut can be helpful to:

- organize existing imports
- remove unneeded imports
- add required imports

You can also adjust the auto-import settings under "Settings → Editor → General → Auto Import"

Answer (score 0):

For Basic Usage Only You can use:

```
   import java.*;
   import javax.*;
```

* is for all

```
   java.*;
```

all classes in java package.

Answer (score 0):

just use somthing like

```html
Import java.*
```