# Importing all Java libraries

Tags: java, import

Is it possible to import all java libraries with

```
import *;
```

or

```
import java.*;
```

?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Each java file must have its own imports for specific classes or packages. This also applies for `static` import as well.

Comment: the latter one is possible - java.*

Comment: @VitaliMelamud AFAIK there's no class in `java` package.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you are right! It's possible compiler-wise but not useful in anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. If you don't want to bother about imports, you better search for an IDE like Eclipse which can automatically import everything you need.

The **widest import you can make** is a single package with a star.

Also this question is already asked with answers:

[asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319016/for-java-can-i-import-all-packages-at-once)

Comment: Ok, then mark it as a duplicated for next time.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You could do the latter, ie. import java.*, but this has no effect since there aren't (at least by default unless you put them in there) any classes in that package. Importing all classes in a given package by using an asterisk, is also not recommended.

In fact, most IDEs have the functionality of automatically organizing your imports, importing only what you really need.

When you import only what you need (given the fact this is trivial using an IDE), you explicitly declare what packages/classes you depend on, making it easy to maintain and refactor later.

If you are not using an IDE, I strongly recommend you use one. For example, I use Eclipse and you can organize your imports automatically by doing a Ctrl + Shift + O, and you can even configure this to happen automatically when you save a file (this is called a "save action").

Comment: I don't think `import java.*` will actually import anything. The `java` package doesn't directly contain any classes.

Comment: Tried this in eclipse. import java.* and allowing eclipse to do the re factoring removes the import and classes say java.util.ArrayList is marked with an error.

Comment: Oops, true. This would work however with subpackages like java.util.*, etc. However, I think the essence of the question is whether one can import massively to (possibly) save some effort. That's why I pointed out that this is not only not recommended, but also that using an IDE makes it trivial to keep your imports clean.

Comment: I believe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807299/is-it-possible-to-import-all-subpackages-at-once-in-java-contrary-to-c-sharp) clarifies what happens when you use an asterisk in your imports:

Comment: @khelwood +1, thanks! I edited the answer, however this is already marked as duplicate so maybe nobody cares anymore :/

Comment: Also I feel my answer has been down-voted unnecessarily :(, at least according to the [Vote Down Privilege Definition](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) ("(down-voting) is not meant as a substitute for communication and editing")