# Does the star import include subpackages in Java?

Tags: java, package

When you declare an import like this:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
```

Does that include everything in its subpackages too? For example, does it include this?

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*
```

If not, why not? (Edit: the "why" question is basically off topic. ignoring that bit when considering a correct answer.)

Comment: @madprogrammer ok thanks, why?

Comment: @Kristian because that's what the language designers decided to do?

Comment: Because that's how it was designed to work. It only includes the classes within the package

Comment: so, they basically were aiming for an eager loading strategy?

Comment: Imports don't affect when classes are loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not. It only imports everything in the package (i.e. the directory itself). Sub-directories are considered to be different packages, so you would need to:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*
```

As to why the language designers chose to go this route, one can only guess, but the system that they decided to go with does allow for a more fine-grained approach.

Comment: There's no need to guess; it's spelled out for us in the JLS.

Comment: @Makoto The rationale behind the decision is spelled out in the JLS? Care to share paragraph number?

Comment: I misread your answer.  I believed that you were looking for how as opposed to "why".  I suppose that the "why" part is a bit of a silly question, as there isn't any way for us to reasonably answer it.

Comment: @Makoto Agreed, that's why I stated that one can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can import all the classes from an import but it does not make it possible to import multiple packages with similar names. For example import java.util*; does not also import java.util.prefs or .jar you have to import these all separately. I don't know if that answers your question, and to the why I am not really sure it just makes sense to do it this way. If you were to import similar packages that had the same static variables, but you only need two or three of the packages then you would get errors or code that does not run properly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a name for these - [type import on demand](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2).

> A type-import-on-demand declaration allows all accessible types of a named package or type to be imported as needed.

They're only also importing the package itself, and not any subpackages, as clarified by the example, emphasis mine:

> `import java.util.*`;
>
> causes the **simple names** of all public types declared in the package `java.util` to be available within the class and interface declarations of the compilation unit. Thus, the simple name `Vector` refers to the type `Vector` in the package `java.util` in all places in the compilation unit where that type declaration is not shadowed (§6.4.1) or obscured (§6.4.2).

Answer (score 1):

> does that include everything in / subdirectories too? including
>   something like this?

`*` stands for all the compilation units inside the package `com.microsoft.azure.storage` where sub packages are actually not compilation units and thus not fetched when you write `myPack.*`. Compilation unit includes `class`, `interface`, `enum` etc.