# Is relationship of a subpackage in one package any different then relationship of two different packages in Java

Tags: java, package

Regarding following Question: [Does the star import include subpackages in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577589/does-the-star-import-include-subpackages-in-java)

so there is nothing special about subpackeges in Java they are considered as totally different packages?

Example: relationship of package A containing subpackage B is the same as relationship of package A to some other Package C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct.

According the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html)

> The hierarchical naming structure for packages is intended to be convenient for organizing related packages in a conventional manner, but has no significance in itself other than the prohibition against a package having a subpackage with the same simple name as a top level type (§7.6) declared in that package.
>
> For example, there is no special access relationship between a package named oliver and another package named oliver.twist, or between packages named evelyn.wood and evelyn.waugh. That is, the code in a package named oliver.twist has no better access to the types declared within package oliver than code in any other package.